# How to match strings with left and right delimiters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following string:

```
$string = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
```

I want to extract every substring that is between **{(|** and **|)}**.

I'm trying:

```
$string = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
preg_match('/([^{\(\|])(.*)([^\|\)}])/', $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3
    [1] => T
    [2] => este 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 
    [3] => 3
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teste 1
    [1] => Teste_2
    [2] => 3 3 3 
)
```

How can I accomplish this result?
Thks!

Comment: You could just use explode for most of it

Comment: `{\(\|([^\|]*)\|\)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is incorrect and you want to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.

```
$str = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
preg_match_all('/{\(\|([^|]*)\|\)}/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teste 1
    [1] => Teste_2
    [2] => 3 3 3 3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way using `str_replace`

```
$string = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
      $array = explode("|)}",str_replace("{(|","",$string));
      print_r(array_slice($array,0, -1));
```

Not the best way but you can keep in mind.

Comment: Thks a lot, Akshay!

Answer (score 2):

can you trying below code

```
<?php

$string = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
preg_match('/{\(\|(.*?)\|\)}{\(\|(.*?)\|\)}{\(\|(.*?)\|\)}/', $string, $matches);    

preg_match_all('/{\(\|(.*?)\|\)}/', $string, $matches_all);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
print_r($matches_all);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thks a lot, YaHui Jiang!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Lookaround` to match the desired output:

```
$string = '{(|Teste 1|)}{(|Teste_2|)}{(|3 3 3 3|)}';
preg_match_all('/(?<=\{\(\|).*?(?=\|\)\})/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/95wUo8/1

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teste 1
    [1] => Teste_2
    [2] => 3 3 3 
)
```

Comment: Thks a lot, Ibrahim!